# Sumar numeros de 1 al 100 bucle for php

Tags: php, php7, bucle-for

buenas noches.

Actualmente comencé a estudiar php, pero estoy estancado en el bucle for,
Tengo un ejercicio en el cual tengo que sumar todos los números del 0 al 100

lo he logrado hacer, pero no me queda claro una parte.

mi código es el siguiente:

```
   <?php
 $resultado = 0;

for($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++){
  $resultado = $resultado + $i;
  echo "<p>$resultado</p>";
}

echo "<h3>El resultado es: $resultado</h3>"
?>
```

Al hacer echo y mostrar en pantalla no logro entender porque si tengo cero, luego aparece el 1

[image: Bucle for]

si el bucle se repite, y las dos variables comienzan en cero, el resultado tendría que ser 0 2 4 y no 0 1 3, eso es lo que no logro entender.

Comment: La primera iteracion es 0 + 0.  La segunda iteracion es 0 + 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ponlo así y entenderás lo que ocurre con el bucle `for`:

```
$resultado = 0;
for($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++){
  echo "i es $i y resultado es $resultado ...";  
  $resultado += $i;
  echo "resultado actual: $resultado\n";      
}
```

---

```
i es 0 y resultado es 0 ...resultado actual: 0
i es 1 y resultado es 0 ...resultado actual: 1
i es 2 y resultado es 1 ...resultado actual: 3
i es 3 y resultado es 3 ...resultado actual: 6
i es 4 y resultado es 6 ...resultado actual: 10
i es 5 y resultado es 10 ...resultado actual: 15
....
```

Lo que ocurre es:

- `$i` y `$resultado` empiezan siendo `0`.
- Se suman en la primera iteracción, dando como resultado `0`
- En la 2ª iteracción `$i` será  `1` y `$resultado` seguirá siendo `0`, por lo que `0+1=1`
- En la 3ª iteracción `$i` será `2` y `$resultado` será `1` por lo que `2+1=3+`
- ...y así sucesivamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora si pude entender.